Is there a way to change keyboard backlight key combination?
My old Dell laptop's keyboard backlight key combination was fn + right arrow which was a super easy combination. On my new Dell laptop, it is fn + f10 and I have to struggle to press it when it gets dark. I can change what a key does on my keyboard using some third party tools like SharpKeys, but it seems these tools can't change fn + xxx keys combinations. Is there a way to achieve this?
